# Is it possible to get time of the day as a metric in AWS Cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I would like to use the `time of the day` as an `input` for a `math expression` in `AWS Cloudwatch metrics`, is there a way to get this metric or I should set a `custom metric` to and publish the time of the day myself?

Comment: CloudWatch math expressions apply some function to one or more existing time series and produces a new time series. What are you trying to do that would require the time as an input to the calculation?

Comment: I’d like to check the time of the day to say for example if night then 0